# How can I setup Rstudio, sparklyR on an auto scale cluster managed by slurm?

Tags: rstudio, autoscaling, slurm, sparklyr

I have an aws HPC auto scale cluster managed by slurm, I can submit jobs using sbatch, however I want to use spraklyr on this cluster so that slurm increases the cluster size based on the workload of the sparklyr code in the R script. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Amir is there a reason you are using slurm here? Sparklyr has better integration with Apache Spark and it would be advisable to run it over a spark cluster. You can follow this Blog to know the steps to setup this up with Amazon EMR which is a Service to run Spark cluster on AWS - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-sparklyr-rstudios-r-interface-to-spark-on-amazon-emr/

Comment: Thanks Austin, The only reason is that the clusters that I have access to already have slurm installed!